# Show only points on the map used by the leaflet package in R

Tags: r, leaflet, scatter-plot

How do I adjust my leaflet code to show only the points? similar to my scatterplot. I inserted below an executable code, as well as a figure comparing the two.
I don't really know how to work with leaflet package. If anyone can help me, I appreciate it.

```
library(leaflet)
library(geosphere)

#database
df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), Latitude = c(-23.2, -23.6, -23.9, -23.9, -23.6,  -23.5, -23.9, -23.9, -23.6, -23.9), 
Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.4, -49.3, -49.9, -49.3, -49.2, -49.6, -49.9)), class="data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -10L))

#clusters
d<-as.dist(distm(df[,2:1]))
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
clusters<-cutree(fit.average, 4) 
df$cluster<-clusters

#Map for Scatterplot
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
g<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude, color=factor(clusters)))+ geom_point()
g

#Map using leaflet
example=df
m=leaflet(data=example)%>%
addTiles() %>%
addPolylines(lat=~Latitude,lng = ~Longitude,color="red")
m
```

[image]
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
addMarkers(lat= ~Latitude, lng = ~Longitude, color= "red")
```

in place of

```
addPolylines(lat= ~Latitude, lng = ~Longitude, color= "red")
```

to have spatial points.
Or use

```
addCircleMarkers(lat=~Latitude, lng = ~Longitude, color= "red")
```

## Update

For assigning same colour to the points that were from the same clusters use the following code

```
getColor <- function(example) {
  sapply(example$cluster, function(cluster) {
    if(cluster == 1) {
      "blue"
    } else if(cluster == 2) {
      "green"
    } else if(cluster == 3) {
      "orange"
    } else {
      "red"
    } })
}

icons <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = getColor(example)
)

leaflet(example) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(lat=~Latitude, lng = ~Longitude, icon=icons, label=~as.character(cluster))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you friend for reply. But, as they are divided into clusters, I need the points that were from the same clusters to have the same color, as it is in the scatterplot. It's possible?

Comment: See my update. Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Thank you friend. It worked. I will accept. However, wouldn't it be possible to do a general function to insert the colors? Because I can have 15 clusters, that way I will have several if else

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question.

Comment: Any idea to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988758/functionality-for-the-confirm-button-that-confirmsweetalert-generates-in-shiny