# Functionality for the Confirm button that confirmSweetAlert generates in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Friends, I would like you to help me with the following question:
The executable code below generates clusters and shows in a table which industries are part of each cluster. However, an alert made by confirmSweetAlert is being displayed when running Shiny to show which industry is being excluded from generating the clusters. ConfirmSweetAlert generates two buttons, the first is "Confirm" and the second is "Not yet". However, I would like to give functionality to "Confirm" that when you press, you no longer display the message at all times from which industry you will be excluded, because every time you change the clusters through the Slider, the same message appears through confirmSweetAlert. The "Not Yet" button functionality, I will develop later, but could you help me with the "Confirm" button, please?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

function.cl<-function(df,k){


  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Industries = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.8,-23.8), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.8, -49.8, -49.5, -49.8, -49.8,-49.8,-49.8), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

  # Exclude long-distance industries
  coordinates<-subset(df,select=c("Latitude","Longitude")) 
  d<-distm(coordinates[,2:1]) 
  diag(d)<-1000000 
  min_distance<-as.matrix(apply(d,MARGIN=2,FUN=min))
  limite<-mean(min_distance)+sd(min_distance) 

  search_vec <- function(mat, vec, dim = 1, tol = 1e-7, fun = all)
    which(apply(mat, dim, function(x) fun((x - vec) > tol)))
  ind_exclude<-search_vec(min_distance,limite,fun=any)
  if(is_empty(ind_exclude)==FALSE){
    for (i in 1:dim(as.array(ind_exclude))){
      df<-subset(df,Industries!=ind_exclude[i])}}


  #cluster
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 


  #Number of clusters
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #Location
  location<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    location[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                    weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  location<-cbind(location,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 


  #Coverage
  coverage<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    aux_dist<-distm(rbind(subset(coordinates,cluster==i),location[i,])[,2:1])
    coverage[i,]<-max(aux_dist[nclusters[i,1]+1,])}
  coverage<-cbind(coverage,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(coverage)<-c("Coverage","cluster")

  #Sum of Waste from clusters
  sum_waste<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    sum_waste[i,]<-sum(subset(df,cluster==i)["Waste"])
  }
  sum_waste<-cbind(sum_waste,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(sum_waste)<-c("Potential","cluster")

  #Output table
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage, sum_waste))
  data_table <- data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Industries)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage + Potential, data_table[,c(1,7,6,2)], toString)


  return(list(
    "IND" =  ind_exclude,
    "Data" = data_table_1
  ))
}


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Clustering "),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      sliderInput("Slider", h3("Number of clusters"),
                  min = 2, max = 6, value = 4),
    ),

    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("tabela")
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

Modelcl<-reactive(function.cl(df,input$Slider))


  output$ind <- renderTable({
    IND <- ((Modelcl()[[1]]))
  })

  observe({
    if(is_empty(Modelcl()[[1]])==FALSE){
      confirmSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        inputId = "myconfirmation",
        btn_labels = c("Confirm", "Not yet"),        
text = tags$div(h5("The industry below is being excluded from clustering:"), 
                        paste(Modelcl()[[1]], collapse = ", ")),
        type="info"
      )
    }})


  output$tabela <- renderDataTable({
    data_table_1 <- req(Modelcl())[[2]]
    x <- datatable(data_table_1[order(data_table_1$cluster), c(1, 4, 2, 3)],
                   options = list(
                     paging =TRUE,
                     pageLength =  5
                   )
    )
    return(x)
  })


  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `reactive` flag (`confirmed_status`) that will change when you confirm via the sweetalert. It will default to false, and an `observeEvent` can be triggered by the result of your alert to change to true when confirmed button is pressed. Then, if you don't want to show the dialog box again after confirming, you can check `confirmed_status` in your `observe` before displaying it again. Let me know if this is the behavior you were looking for.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  confirmed_status <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

  Modelcl<-reactive(function.cl(df,input$Slider))

  output$ind <- renderTable({
    IND <- ((Modelcl()[[1]]))
  })

  observe({
    if(is_empty(Modelcl()[[1]])==FALSE && isFALSE(confirmed_status())){
      confirmSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        inputId = "myconfirmation",
        btn_labels = c("Confirm", "Not yet"),        
        text = tags$div(h5("The industry below is being excluded from clustering:"), 
                        paste(Modelcl()[[1]], collapse = ", ")),
        type="info"
      )
    }})

  observeEvent(input$myconfirmation, {
    if (isFALSE(input$myconfirmation)) {
      confirmed_status(TRUE)
    } else {
      # Add here more for the "Not yet" condition
    }
  })

  output$tabela <- renderDataTable({
    data_table_1 <- req(Modelcl())[[2]]
    x <- datatable(data_table_1[order(data_table_1$cluster), c(1, 4, 2, 3)],
                   options = list(
                     paging =TRUE,
                     pageLength =  5
                   )
    )
    return(x)
  })

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for responding, it worked, but I wanted to clarify a few points. I didn't understand how you specified the functionality for the button that I called "Confirm". And if I wanted that same functionality for the "Not yet" button. How would it be? I thought it would be something like this in the observeEvent you did:  ```observeEvent (input$myconfirmation ==" Confirm "......```. Can't specify the button exactly?

Comment: After your `if` statement, add `else` which would cover the situation if someone pressed the "Not yet" button. You don't need another `observeEvent`, since it will be triggered with either button. I edited the answer showing this.

Comment: Oh, I understood, really, I had forgotten that. But if I wanted to do it the way I talked about specifying the button exactly, how would it be?

Comment: `confirmSweetAlert` appears to use the "cancel" button first (FALSE), and the "confirm" button second (TRUE) when listing the buttons in `btn_labels` argument. That is how it is described in the example and documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.5.2/topics/sweetalert-confirmation).

Comment: Ben, I hope you are okay. Could you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702454/adjust-fileinput-and-reset-in-shiny