# Adjust fileinput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I inserted a `df` database as a sample for you to see how it looks, but I would like to load this `df` database from `fileInput`,that is, this database will be in "xlsx" format and I will go load by `fileInput`. Could you help me adjust this?

Thank you so much!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(df,date,d1,d2){
  
  df <- structure(
   list(date = c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03","2021-01-04","2021-01-05"),
         d1 = c(0,1,4,5,6), d2 = c(2,4,5,6,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
}    
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   fileInput("file", "Please upload a file"),
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       selectInput("date", label = h4("Date"),""),
                                       selectInput("d1", label = h4("D1"),""),
                                       selectInput("d2", label = h4("D2"),""),
                                       br(),
                                       actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl())
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "date", label = "Date", unique(data()$date))
    updateSelectInput(session, "d1", label = "D1", unique(data()$d1))
    updateSelectInput(session, "d2", label = "D2", unique(data()$d2))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
data <- eventReactive(input$file, {
    if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    df <- read_excel(input$file$datapath)
    df
  })
```